# Akeneo: Clone a product

Tags: akeneo

We need to clone a product in Akeneo 1.4 (only the SKU should change).

I've found a similar questions ([1](http://www.akeneo.com/forums/topic/easy-way-to-clone-product/), [2](http://www.akeneo.com/forums/topic/product-duplication/)) in the Akeneo forum, but no answer for the most interesting parts:

- clone product (PimCatalogProduct)
- clone product values list (PimCatalogProductValue) and attributes
- ...

Should I use `ProductPropertyCopier`, `ProductTemplateBuilder`, ... for this?

Do the target attributes already need to exists when using the`ProductPropertyCopier`?

Is there now in Akeneo 1.4 an easier way to clone a product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akeneo does not come with a native way to duplicate products but it's a common need and we are aware of this problem we may prioritise it in the future.

The easiest way to duplicate a product is to normalize it and denormalize it right after that:

```
$normalizedProduct = $this->serializer->normalize($sourceProduct, 'csv');
$duplicatedProduct = $this->serializer->denormalize(
    $normalizedProduct,
    'Pim\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Model\Product',
    'csv',
    [
         'entity' => new Pim\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Model\Product()
    ]
);

// You can now modify the product identifier :)

$this->productSaver->save($duplicatedProduct);
```

Your product is now duplicated and ready to be used !

Comment: Great, I didn't expected such a simple solution, thanks!

Comment: The `denormalize` doesn't work like this with Akeneo 1.5: "Could not denormalize object of type Pim\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Model\Product, no supporting normalizer found.". Could you give me a hint, how I can migrate this to Akeneo 1.5?

Comment: From Ronan in the Akeneo forum:
"the method still works, bu the Product class has been moved.
try changing Pim\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Model\Product to Pim\Component\Catalog\Model\Product in your code."