# Akeneo 1.6: Clone a product

Tags: clone, akeneo

We need to clone a product in Akeneo 1.6 (only the SKU should change).

We used the method described in the response to my [old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823406/akeneo-clone-a-product), but this seems only to work in Akeneo 1.4 and 1.5.

I've tried to normalize the product to JSON, but I haven't found an easy way to write it back into a Product. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way is to use the [ProductQueryBuilder](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/1.6/src/Pim/Component/Catalog/Query/ProductQueryBuilder.php) to fetch product from the database, then normalize them in array with the [ProductNormalizer](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/1.6/src/Pim/Component/Catalog/Normalizer/Structured/ProductNormalizer.php), change the SKU then use the [ProductBuilder](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/1.6/src/Pim/Component/Catalog/Builder/ProductBuilder.php) to create a product. You can now update it with the [ProductUpdater](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/1.6/src/Pim/Component/Catalog/Updater/ProductUpdater.php) and save it with the [ProductSaver](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/1.6/src/Pim/Bundle/CatalogBundle/Doctrine/Common/Saver/ProductSaver.php).

Or if you don't want to develop anything you can export the desired products, change their SKU then reimport them :)

Comment: Thanks, this works :-). I normalize the product to `json`, take the `values` array, set there groups, categories, enabled, associations and then create, update and save the product.